# Enlace de un registro de una pagina a otra mediante un GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien, por medio de la presente agradezco por favor cualquier ayuda respecto a un inconveniente que se me presenta en una aplicación en C# Asp.net referente al envió de datos de una página a otra por medio de un hiperenlace o hipervínculo, tengo una página de origen y otra de destino, el página de origen tiene como nombre Default.Aspx , cuyos componentes son los siguientes:

Pero hago especial énfasis en la grilla (GridView) con nombre GridView1 en donde al dar clic en cualquier registro el campo Código_alumno , me tiene que llevar a la página (NombreAlumnos.aspx) de destino con el código del alumno ya seleccionado

Para ello he realizado lo siguiente, en el archivo de origen tengo el siguiente código en Default.aspx :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Código_alumno" >
    <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<% # Eval("codalumno") %>' OnClick="lnk1_Onclick"  CommandName="Select" > <%# Eval("codalumno") %> </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

 Y en Default.aspx.cs:
public void lnk1_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) // protected
   {
      string codalumno1 = ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
             Response.Redirect("NotasAlumnos.aspx?codalumno1=" + codalumno1);
             return;
      }
```

Y en el archivo de destino (NombreAlumnos.aspx.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CRUDPruebas
{
    public partial class NotasAlumnos : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack) {

                if (Request.QueryString["codalumno1"] == null) return;
                
                codalumno1.Text = Request.QueryString["codalumno1"].ToString();
                return;  
            }
   return;
        }
```

Al ejecutar el programa al momento de realizar el paso a paso de la ejecución del mismo me hace lo siguiente:

Default.aspx.cs     evento page_load
Me envia al archivo siteMaster.cs
Escojo valor del gridview (Codigo_alumno)
Me devuelve a Default.aspx.cs     evento page_load
Me envia de nuevo al archivo siteMaster.cs
Vuelve al lnk1_onclick:
En donde en
Response.Redirect("NotasAlumnos.aspx?codalumno1=" + codalumno1);
Me toma el valor seleccionado (codalumno1)
Luego me devuelve al Default.aspx.cs    al evento page_load y me devuelve al GetEmployeeList(), en donde me dice que hay un error de servidor en la aplicación, en esta parte es en donde surge mi inquietud ya que no debería devolverme a enviar al Default.aspx.cs sino que automáticamente  me debería de enviar a la página NotasAlumnos.aspx e imprimirme en el texto codalumno1, el registro seleccionado.

En el siguiente enlace explico aun mas a profundidad el requerimiento

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSd4orjr-8U
```

Muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: Puedes ser más explícito en describir en "error de servidor en la aplicación", que mensaje te sale?

Comment: Cordial saludo, muchas gracias por el interés, en el siguiente video explico de manera mas profunda  la descripción del error  "error de servidor en la aplicación":   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6-zM5rW1WA, saludos!.

Comment: Sale el mensaje que el video es privado, puedes indicarnos el mensaje que te sale en el mensaje de tu post, sería de gran ayuda